# Android crashing when i take a picture on a real samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, crash, camera, save, onactivityresult

i made an application that will allow the user to take a camera shot and edit it using my application. I own a samsung galaxy stellar and it works fine on it. I had my friend download the application and when she tested it on her phone, my application crashes whenever she takes a picture and hit "save". shes using a galaxy s3.

Heres my code when im taking a picture

```
case R.id.ibTakePic:

i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+File.sep    arator + fileName2 + ".jpg");
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
rotatePic = true;
startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
break;
```

and heres my result code..

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            pictake = true;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            rotatePic = false;
            bmpReceive = rotate(picturePath);

            bmpOriginal = bmpReceive; 

            picTaken.setImageBitmap(bmpReceive);
   //         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
     //       imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


        }
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: UHhhh i dont know about the stack trace because my friend is far away from me. From what she told me, as soon as she click save. the screen goes black and says my app has stopped working.

Comment: @CarloBrew As your friend saying that screen goes black and after try to save the image. I guess it must be the issue of `outOfMemory`

Comment: If that's the case then, any idea on how can i fix it? I am doing some researching at the moment but no luck so far

Comment: You can decompress or resize the image after saving it.

Comment: But i have been resizing it already to like 400 x 500 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem so I switched to this:

```
Uri uri= data.getData();
InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, Logs help. But here is my guess.

If you check the Documentation.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html

A query can return a Cursor object or null.
In your code you are not checking for the null. I suggest you try with that. In any case you should always put null checks wherever there is a chance for a null to be returned.

If you can provide the logs then we can tell you the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the bitmap is too big and you get an out of memory. Check that page to know how to deal with that situation:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html